# loop through database with cursor updating records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody help me to complete this task..

```
   FirstName  LastName  EmpNumber  EffectiveFrom   EffectiveTo    JobTitle
      john     A        EMP01      2004-05-01      2005-09-01     credit officer
      NULL     NULL     NULL       2005-09-01      2006-30-01     chief credit officer
      NULL     NULL     NULL       2006-30-01      2006-30-09
      george   B        EMP02      
      david    C        EMP03
      NULL     NULL     NULL
      NULL     NULL     NULL
```

I have such table and want to update it with cursor to look like this
i didn't write all data just some records

```
 FirstName  LastName  EmpNumber   EffectiveFrom   EffectiveTo    JobTitle
     john      A       EMP01 
     john      A       EMP01 
     john      A       EMP01 
     george    B       EMP02 
     david     C       EMP03 
     david     C       EMP03 
     david     C       EMP03
```

Comment: What are your column names? Is all that data in a single row, or are there 3 rows?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to create duplicates? just delete the `null` rows: `delete from your_table where col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null`

Comment: OK, now there's nothing to distinguish the NULL records, so you can't tell it which row to update. Are there some other columns you're not showing?

Comment: Do you simply want the record updated in the order they are with the last non null row when all fields are null?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @SeanW  there are date records if it can help..

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio - yes i want to do such thing

Comment: @juergend - there will not be dublicate records, becouse there are other colomns and there will not be dublicate record

Comment: Xurca, even if there are dates linking to nulls, just knowing "1/1/2012" doesn't let you know that row links to John A. How do you know which date links to which employee? Is there a general employee table you can link on ID's? These null value tables seem useless unless there's more info you can give us. Are there multiple tables for this query, or is your table just the listed columns? Is there an ordering so you know how they relate? Is there a primary key to order by so you can list them in order to link?

Comment: @Corey - there is another employee table wich is connected to this table with EmpNumber, and there is no problem with dublicates, all this records are unique except that i want just update this null values in the order they are, with the last none null row

Comment: @xurca please take a look to my answer, ¿is it what you need? I also want to know if you need this for a one time only procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create variables to hold the last not null values found: `@FirstNameNN, @LastNameNN, @EmpNumberNN.`

Create a cursor and fetch each row saving its data to variables (`@FirstName, @LastName, @EmpNumber, @EffectiveFrom, @EffectiveTo, @JobTitle`).

In each cursor iteration, do something like this:

```
IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @FirstNameNN = @FirstName
    SET @LastNameNN = @LastName
    SET @EmpNumberNN = @EmpNumber 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Employees
      SET FirstName = @FirstNameNN,
          LastName = @LastNameNN,
          EmpNumber = @EmpNumberNN
    WHERE EffectiveFrom = @EffectiveFrom AND
          EffectiveTo = @EffectiveTo AND
          JobTitle = @JobTitle
END
```

Of course, if there are two rows with the last three columns being equal, this code will fail.

Comment: What I would add to this is, first: add an IDENTITY column to the table. Second, make sure the data is in the correct order in respect to that column. Third, the create cursor should be ordered by the new IDENTITY column. Fourth, instead of updating with the above WHERE clause, you can now use the IDENTITY column. Fifth, drop the IDENTITY column.

Comment: You could even do the update WITHOUT a cursor, if you have the IDENTITY column. Just join the table back to itself where joined table ID is < main table ID, and the joined table ID is max(ID with not nulls). If that makes sense. Then it's just a single query update.

Comment: @SeanW I agree with both of your comments. Cursors are evil but I suppose this is a one time operation so it's not a big deal. It woldn't be so easy to ensure an Id column will have the info in that order, I really hope the OP is asking for help on cleaning this data  in order to start using a better process where all records are stored with their full data.

Comment: @SeanW - i need this for filling this table completely so that i can than import all this data into main table, it is data of history of employees work

Comment: did you get it sorted? or do you still need help? where have you got to?

Comment: @SeanW - i made it without cursor just created temporary table with  IDENTITY colomn and inserted all data into it, and then updated records...

Answer (score 0):

i also made it with cursor too, just copied where statements from @daniloquio code.

```
 DECLARE @NAME  NVARCHAR(500), @LastName NVARCHAR(500), @EmpN NVARCHAR(500), @TN NVARCHAR(500), @TLN NVARCHAR(500), @TEN NVARCHAR(500),
                @EffectiveFrom DATETIME,@EffectiveTo DATETIME,@JobTitle NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE temp CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  Name, [Last Name], [Employee Number], [Effective From], [Effective To], [Job Title]
    FROM dbo.Positions$

    OPEN temp       

FETCH NEXT FROM temp INTO @Name, @LastName, @EmpN, @EffectiveFrom, @EffectiveTo, @JobTitle

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Name, @LastName, @EmpN

    IF @NAME IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TN=@NAME, @TLN=@LastName, @TEN=@EmpN
    END
    ELSE
     BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Positions$
        SET Name=@TN, 
                [Last Name]=@TLN, 
                [Employee Number]=@TEN 
        WHERE [Effective From] = @EffectiveFrom AND
          [Effective To] = @EffectiveTo AND
          [Job Title] = @JobTitle
     END


    FETCH NEXT FROM temp INTO @Name, @LastName, @EmpN, @EffectiveFrom, @EffectiveTo, @JobTitle
END
CLOSE temp;
DEALLOCATE temp;
```